# Base62 codificação

Tags: php, algoritmo, base64

Gostaria de saber onde posso obter alguma implementação em PHP, semelhante ao **MIME Base64** do PHP mas que conte apenas com os caracteres de A-Z, a-z e 0-9.

O **Base64 do PHP** é bastante versátil, mas preciso de um algoritmo que não contemple os caracteres `+`, `/`, `-` e `=`. Sei que posso substituir os caracteres mencionados para efeitos de um **URL**, que até nem é o caso, mas pretendia mesmo um algoritmo de codificação directo.

A codificação de números para **base62**, é linear, mas pretendia a codificação de uma string PHP binária. Importante realizar o **encode** e o **decode**.

Alguém me pode indicar alguma implementação prática?

Comment: https://github.com/vinkla/base62

Comment: @gmsantos agradeço a referência mas já conhecia, mas como expliquei para mim a codificação Base62 de valores numéricos é básica e linear. O que pretendo é um codificador com o range (A-Z, a-z e 0-9) mas para strings. E isso não encontro e acho que tenho mesmo de desenvolver um e na unha mesmo. Mas agradeço o seu tempo.

Comment: @chambelix Viu a minha resposta?

Comment: @Victor vi e vou responder estou a analisar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue a implementação.

- Implementado em duas linguagens diferentes: PHP e em Java.
- Permite você especificar o alfabeto no construtor.
- O tamanho do alfabeto é obtido a partir do próprio alfabeto.
- Deve funcionar para qualquer tamanho de alfabeto >= 2 e < 256.
- O funcionamento do `encode` consiste em interpretar a `String` de entrada como um número base-256 a ser convertido em `BigInteger`. Em seguida, o `BigInteger` é convertido para uma `String` em base-62 (ou qualquer outra, de acordo com o alfabeto dado).
- O funcionamento do `decode` é apenas o inverso do `encode`. Recebe a `String` como se fosse um número em base-62 (ou qualquer outra), converte para `BigInteger` e então converte o `BigInteger` para uma `String` base-256.

## PHP:

Eis o código:

```php
<?php

include('Math/BigInteger.php');

class BaseN {

    private $base;
    private $radix;
    private $bi256, $one, $zero;

    function __construct($base) {
        $this->base = $base;
        $this->radix = new Math_BigInteger(strlen($base));
        $this->bi256 = new Math_BigInteger(256);
        $this->zero = new Math_BigInteger(0);
        $this->one = new Math_BigInteger(1);
    }

    public function encode($text) {
        $big = $this->one;
        for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($text); $j++) {
            $big = $big->multiply($this->bi256)->add(new Math_BigInteger(ord($text[$j])));
        }
        $result = "";
        while (!$this->zero->equals($big)) {
            $parts = $big->divide($this->radix);
            $small = intval($parts[1]->toString());
            $big = $parts[0];
            $result = $this->base[$small] . $result;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function decode($text) {
        $big = $this->zero;
        for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($text); $j++) {
            $i = strpos($this->base, $text[$j]);
            $big = $big->multiply($this->radix)->add(new Math_BigInteger($i));
        }
        $result = "";
        while (!$this->zero->equals($big)) {
            $parts = $big->divide($this->bi256);
            $small = $parts[1]->toBytes();
            $big = $parts[0];
            $result = $small . $result;
        }
        return substr($result, 1);
     }
}

?>
```

Modo de usar:

```php
// Passa o alfabeto como parâmetro. Tem 62 caracteres aqui, então são 62 símbolos.
$k = new BaseN("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
$x = "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog";
echo $x . "\n";
$c = $k->encode($x);
echo $c . "\n"; // Escreve "1u9WLfG65OMtVkQWPtWDcC6o8IjI5td5l9DzpilIK4Nyx81tKLRrStPj"
$d = $k->decode($c);
echo $d . "\n"; // Escreve "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog"
```

[Veja aqui no ideone](https://ideone.com/gmnEno) (não se assuste com o tamanho do código, tive que colocar a classe `BigInteger` inteira lá).

## Em Java

E, caso alguém se interesse, eu também implementei em Java. Eis o código:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class BaseN {
    private static final BigInteger BI_256 = BigInteger.valueOf(256);

    private final String base;
    private final BigInteger radix;

    public BaseN(String base) {
        this.base = base;
        this.radix = BigInteger.valueOf(base.length());
    }

    public String encode(String text) {
        byte[] bytes = text.getBytes();
        BigInteger big = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            big = big.multiply(BI_256).add(BigInteger.valueOf(b));
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 4 / 3 + 2);
        while (!BigInteger.ZERO.equals(big)) {
            BigInteger[] parts = big.divideAndRemainder(radix);
            int small = parts[1].intValue();
            big = parts[0];
            sb.append(base.charAt(small));
        }

        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }

    public String decode(String text) {
        BigInteger big = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            int i = base.indexOf(c);
            if (i == -1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            big = big.multiply(radix).add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }

        List<Byte> byteList = new ArrayList<>(text.length());
        while (!BigInteger.ZERO.equals(big)) {
            BigInteger[] parts = big.divideAndRemainder(BI_256);
            int small = parts[1].intValue();
            big = parts[0];
            byteList.add((byte) small);
        }
        Collections.reverse(byteList);

        byte[] r = new byte[byteList.size() - 1];
        int i = 0;
        for (Byte b : byteList) {
            if (i > 0) r[i - 1] = b;
            i++;
        }
        return new String(r);
    }
}
```

Modo de usar:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Passa o alfabeto como parâmetro. Tem 62 caracteres aqui, então são 62 símbolos.
        BaseN bn = new BaseN("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        String x = "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog";
        System.out.println(x);
        String a = bn.encode(x);
        System.out.println(a); // Escreve "1u9WLfG65OMtVkQWPtWDcC6o8IjI5td5l9DzpilIK4Nyx81tKLRrStPj"
        String b = bn.decode(a);
        System.out.println(b); // Escreve "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog"
    }
}
```

[Veja aqui no ideone](https://ideone.com/KDMyH7).

Comment: dou os meus parabéns pois você acabou de me entregar um algoritmo que me vai poupar algumas horas... ainda por cima você utiliza o Math_BigInteger como eu. Só posso votar uma vez e já o fiz porque senão votava mais vezes na tua resposta. Deixe me dizer que a sua solução é completa e o código bem estruturado. Posso usar em meu código? Quanto à solução em JAVA é a cereja em cima do bolo.

Comment: @chambelix Claro que pode usar! :) Fico grato em ter ajudado, pois este daqui foi bem desafiador e interessante de fazer.

Comment: Ocorre um erro em determinados tamanhos de string no encode na linha $small=ord($parts[1]->toBytes()[0]). Mas já apanhei...mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: @chambelix Me explique melhor o erro. Odeio bugs. Que string você usou?

Comment: @chambelix Acho que tenho uma solução para este bug, mas primeiro preciso de um caso de teste que o reproduza para confirmar se minha correção funciona. O problema é que não encontrei nenhum caso que reproduza o bug ainda, então se você puder me fornecer, corrijo com prazer. :)

Comment: tente a string "excelente solução" vai dar certo, mas se adicionar mais um espaço entre as palavras ou colocar mais um caracter... vai dar erro. estou aqui a acabar um código  só vou analisar o seu algoritmo depois e resolver o erro. se não se quiser incomodar depois dou resposta. erros são normais.

Comment: @chambelix: https://ideone.com/Mu6ZGh - `excelente  solução` o encode gerou `p0KO2123BeMgaOUElggUpPOWYFb` que gerou `excelente  solução` no decode, ou seja, funcionou. No entanto o `ç` e o `ã` me fazem querer olhar para problemas de encoding.

Comment: @chambelix `PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /home/miR2Be/prog.php on line 1990` - Ok, já dou um jeito nisso...

Comment: a mim "excelente solução1" me dá o erro "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0"... no entanto tentei uma abordagem direta ao problema e coloquei... if (isset($parts[1]->toBytes()[0])) {
                $small = ord($parts[1]->toBytes()[0]);
            } else {
                $small = 0;
            } ---> e resolve!

Comment: @chambelix Corrigido. :)

Comment: já vi :) mais uma vez os meus parabéns... corrigidissimo!

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode ter algo representado em base64 com apenas este range de caracteres **(A-Z, a-z e 0-9) pois este range conta com apenas 62 caracteres e base64 exige 64 representações distintas**.

Então se você não quiser os caracteres **+** e **/** na sua representação em base64, precisará substituí-los por outra coisa fora deste range. Terá que escolher uma substituição para o **=** também pois ele pode aparecer numa representação em base64 a fim de completar o tamanho do último bloco.

O que tem sido usado na prática, quando da necessidade por exemplo de incluir uma representação base64 em uma URL, é substituir o conjunto {**+** **/** **=**} por {**-** **_** **,**}, respectivamente.

Numa pesquisa rápida, me pareceu que PHP não possui nativamente uma função para isso, de modo que você terá que implementar a sua própria.

Mesmo que sua intenção não seja a utilização em URL, [esta idéia](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#Hcom82200) deve lhe servir:

```
function base64url_encode($plainText) {

    $base64 = base64_encode($plainText);
    $base64url = strtr($base64, '+/=', '-_,');
    return $base64url;   
}

function base64url_decode($plainText) {

    $base64url = strtr($plainText, '-_,', '+/=');
    $base64 = base64_decode($base64url);
    return $base64;   
}
```

**Update:** Acabou de me ocorrer também que você pode converter seus bytes para **Hexadecimal**, o qual é representado apenas por 0-9 e A-F. A string resultante fica bem maior que na representação base64, mas talvez lhe sirva. Não conheço função PHP que faça isso mas a lógica de conversão de bytes para hexadecimal é bastante simples.

Comment: Não acho que seja isso que ele quer. Pelo que entendi, ele quer um algoritmo de codificação em base-62, e não representar um base-64 com 62 símbolos distintos. E mesmo assim, existe formas de você representar base-64 com 62 símbolos. Por exemplo, você usa 61 símbolos normalmente (`0`-`9`, `A`-`Z` e `a`-`y`), e então usa `za`, `zb` e `zc` para corresponderem aos três símbolos distintos restantes, aonde `z` não pode aparecer no final e nem seguido de algo que não seja `a`, `b` ou `c`.

Comment: @Victor Existem 1001 formas de representar qualquer valor de qualquer maneira, e você pode inventar mais uma - igual Neston. Basta fazer uma funçãozinha como esta que colei na minha resposta :-)

Comment: sim, exatamente. É que na sua resposta você diz *Você não pode ter algo representado em base64 com apenas este range de caracteres*, e eu acabei de mostrar uma forma de fazer isso. :)

Comment: @Victor, todos sabemos que entre o céu e a terra há mais coisas do que sonha a nossa filosofia; então escrevemos *"sim"*, *"não"*, *"sempre"*, *"nunca"* sem medo porque sabemos que em algum grau ou em algum momento ou de algum ponto de vista algo será diferente do que foi afirmado - e os sábios nos lêem sem levar ao extremo estas palavras porque sabem o mesmo e sabem que sabíamos ao escrever. Por isso não se preocupe, apenas escreva uma resposta com as suas idéias e ela terá o potencial de ajudar alguém. Se não ajudar, o mecanismo do SO (votos, moderação..) cuida para que também não atrapalhe.

Comment: @Caffé agradeço e muito o seu tempo mas como referi na minha pergunta mencionei que "Sei que posso substituir os caracteres mencionados para efeitos de um URL" e conheço muito bem o algoritmo Base64 a sua aplicabilidade. A sua resposta está um pouco fora da minha pergunta... Mas agradeço o tempo que perdeu.