# Converter milissegundos em um hexadecimal de 16 dígitos

Tags: php

Estou a implementar um algoritmo para gerar uma chave de acesso a um determinado sistema, entretanto surgiu a necessidade de converter um valor numérico para hexadecimal de 16 dígitos.

Considere o número de milissegundos decorridos desde 1º de janeiro de 1970:

```
$milliseconds = (time()*1000);
//1530747443000
```

É possível converter o valor em milissegundos em um hexadecimal de 16 dígitos?

Comment: @FelipeMoraes o maior valor convertido é `4294967295`, e a variável `$milliseconds` é mais de 300x maior. Não pode ser uma conversão de partes da variável para formar um hexa de 16 dígitos?

Comment: @WeesSmith As instruções para criar o algoritmo diz para obter o número de segundos decorridos desde janeiro de 1970 e depois diz para converter os milissegundos em um hexadecimal de 16 digitos. Eu já tentei utilizar funções do PHP que fazem essa conversão mas não consegui obter 16 digitos, apenas adicionando caracteres aleatórios.

Comment: Rapaz, estou quebrando a cabeça para tentar achar um hexa de 16 digitos kk

Comment: @WeesSmith Pelo que percebi não há como, somente adicionando caracteres a esquerda como na resposta. Entretanto vi no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610603/help-me-translate-long-value-expressed-in-hex-back-in-to-a-date-time) o contrário, alguém tentando converter o hexadecimal de 16 digitos em data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php), `dechex()` suporta somente inteiros com valores até `4294967295`.

Nesse caso, você precisa escrever uma função capaz de converter inteiros grandes para hexadecimal, veja só:

```
<?php

function bcdechex($dec) {
    $hex = '';
    do {    
        $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
        $hex = dechex($last).$hex;
        $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
    } while($dec>0);
    return str_pad($hex, 16, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

$hexstr = bcdechex( time() * 1000 );

echo $hexstr;

?>
```

Saída:

```
0000016467d83520
```

Comment: Obrigado porém não resulta em um hexadecimal de 16 digitos, além da função `time()` retornar o tempo decorrido em segundos.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes: Entendi, segue edição

Comment: Eu já verifiquei essas funções, inclusive a documentação do PHP porém preciso que seja uma hexadecimal de 16 digitos para implementar o algoritmo corretamente. A função não está a devolver um hexadecimal de 16 digitos.

Comment: A função está retornado o valor hexadecimal corretamente. Acontece que os zeros a esquerda estão sendo suprimidos.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes: Agora está ok. Resposta editada!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `Math/BigInteger` para resolver o seu problema e com ele criar um conversor em hexadecimal facilmente:

```
<?php

include('Math/BigInteger.php');

function toHex($n) {
    $zero = new Math_BigInteger(0);
    if ($n->compare($zero) == 0) return "0";
    $base = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    $dezesseis = new Math_BigInteger(16);
    $result = "";
    while ($n->compare($zero) > 0) {
        list($n, $r) = $n->divide($dezesseis);
        $result = $base[intval($r->toString())] . $result;
    }
    return $result;
}

function milliToHex() {
    $temp = new Math_BigInteger(time());
    $mil = new Math_BigInteger(1000);
    $ret = toHex($temp->multiply($mil));
    return str_pad($ret, 16, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo milliToHex();

?>
```

Para mim, produziu essa saída:

```
0000016468976E40
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone**](https://ideone.com/8QP4L1) (mas não se assuste com o tamanho do código, pois tive que copiar e colar a classe `Math/BigInteger` praticamente inteira lá no ideone).

Também já fiz [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47274/132) há três anos e meio atrás que usa alguns conceitos similares.